# Reverse function not working properly

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.4

I created my own function to reverse the words in a phrase such as:

```
reverse("Hello my name is Bob")
Bob is name my Hello
```

This is the code that I have

```
def first_word(string):
    first_space_pos = string.find(" ")
    word = string[0:first_space_pos]
    return word

def last_words(string):
    first_space_pos = string.find(" ")
    words = string[first_space_pos+1:]
    return words

def reverse(string):
    words = string.count(" ") +1
    count = 1
    string_reversed = ""
    while count <= words:
        string_reversed = first_word(string) + str(" ") + string_reversed
        string = last_words(string)
        count += 1
    return string_reversed
```

Whenever I enter a string, the last letter of the first word of the phrase always gets cut off

```
reverse("Hello my name is Bob")
Bob is name my Hell
```

The "o" is missing in Hello. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: what happens when you print the first word each time? does it show Hell or Hello?

Comment: you mean when I do just reverse("Hello")? It shows Hell with a space after it

Comment: no just before you return the first word, print it out. see what happens?

Comment: first_word("Hello my name is Bob") yields Hello

Comment: for me, you code prints `Bo is name my Hello `

Comment: yes, thats the problem for me right now. the 2nd "b" in Bob is not being returned in the reverse()

Answer (score 2):

Although you can use [::-1] to get a reversed list, you can also use `reversed`, cause it's more readable and explicit.

```
>>> words = "Hello my name is Bob"
>>> ' '.join(reversed(words.split(' ')))
'Bob is name my Hello'
```

Comment: i'm afraid he has to use his own functions

Answer (score 1):

Keep it simple,

```
>>> ' '.join("Hello my name is Bob".split()[::-1])
'Bob is name my Hello'
```

OR

```
>>> l = "Hello my name is Bob".split()[::-1]
>>> s = ""
>>> for i,j in enumerate(l):
    if i != 0:
        s += ' ' + j
    else:
        s += j


>>> s
'Bob is name my Hello'
>>>
```

Comment: The assignment is to use utilize 2 different functions to create it, so I can't use join

Comment: No the thing is the instructions is to use the functions first_word and last_word, I would do it another way if I had the choice to. Please help me with the way I'm doing it

Comment: @HelloWorld: if you could only describe what the function are meant to do -> `first_word(...)` does what? reverses the first word of a list? returns a first word of a string? (even though it is obvious from you code; you can improve it: `def first_word(s): return s.split(" ")[0]`.

Please do not use `string` as a parameter, as it could shadow with built-in `string` module. (even though now it is not the case)

Comment: first_word() returns first word of a string and last_words() returns the remainder of the string

Answer (score 1):

you need to modify your loop slightly

```
def reverse(string):
words = string.count(" ") +1
count = 1
string_reversed = ""

while count < words:

    string_reversed = first_word(string) + str(" ") + string_reversed

    string = last_words(string)

    count += 1

print(string + " " + string_reversed)
return string + " " + string_reversed
```

Comment: Now when i do reverse("Hello my name is Bob"), it returns "Bo is"

Comment: please see now, i have made a change

Comment: Now I'm getting 'is name my Hello Bob'

Comment: this one prints Bob is name my Hello

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is with this code:

```
def first_word(string):
    first_space_pos = string.find(" ")
    word = string[0:first_space_pos]
    return word
```

When you get to the iteration of your loop in the `reverse` function, you are sending a string without any spaces (because your string consists of the final word to be processed), so `string.find(" ")` is returning `-1`.  Easiest solution is to replace it with the below:

```
def first_word(string):
    first_space_pos = string.find(" ")
    if first_space_pos == -1:
        first_space_pos = len(string)
    word = string[0:first_space_pos]
    return word
```

(This is assuming that you have to modify and use the functions above - other answers provide better ways to implement the functionality)